# How do I get around this? IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, branch-and-bound

When I run my code, I receive this IndexError:

```
constraints[fr][to] = self.extra_constr[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here a sample of my code:

```
def determine_constr(self, parent_constr):
    constraints = copy.deepcopy(parent_constr)
    if self.extra_constr == None:
        return constraints

    fr = self.extra_constr[0]
    to = self.extra_constr[1]
    constraints[fr][to] = self.extra_constr[2]
    constraints[to][fr] = self.extra_constr[2]

    for i in range(2):
        constraints = self.removeEdges(constraints)
        constraints = self.addEdges(constraints)

    return constraints
```

Comment: This just means that your index is referencing an element beyond the end of the list.  So, check your lists to see which one it is.  For example, `self.extra_constr` must have length at least 3 to use index 2.  Does it?  Check it.

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because either

- `fr` is out of range for `constraints`
- `to` is out of range for `constraints[fr]`
- or `2` is out of range for `self.extra_constr`

Without more details as to what these variables contain, it's hard to answer your question any more precisely.

You can double check which one of them is causing the error by using assertions in your code. For instance:

```
assert fr in range(len(constraints))
assert to in range(len(constraints[fr]))
assert 2 in range(len(self.extra_constr))
```

These will throw an `AssertionError` if the indexes are out of range, and help you debug your code!